# Derivative of a Matrix with respect to a vector following the chain rule

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

\usepackage{amsmath}

I have a 2$\times$2 matrix $\bf \underline{A}$ that is a function of a 2-vector $\bf \overrightarrow u$ where

$$
{\bf \overrightarrow u}=[p,v]^{\text T}
$$

such that

$$
\begin{equation*}
{\bf \underline{A}}({\bf \overrightarrow u}) =
\begin{bmatrix}
-v & f(p) \\\\
g(p) & -v
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
$$

where $f(p)$ and $g(p)$ are continuous real functions, and the real variables $p$ and $v$ are in turn functions of an independent real variable $t$.

I need to evaluate the time derivative of ${\bf \underline{A}}$. The problem with component-by-component differentiation is that as this matrix derivative is embedded in an explicit finite-difference scheme, these time derivatives do not conveniently fit into the computational stencil.

Therefore, I have expanded the derivative of the matrix ${\bf \underline{A}}$ with respect to $t$ as

$$
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial{\bf \underline{A}}}{\partial {t}}=
\Biggl[\frac{\partial{\bf \underline{A}}}{\partial {{\bf \overrightarrow u}}}\Biggr]
\frac{\partial {{\bf \overrightarrow u}}}{\partial {t}}
\end{equation*}
$$

This form is convenient because the finite difference scheme directly involves the the vector ${\bf \overrightarrow u}$ and its derivatives.

I would imagine that the partial derivative in brackets is a 3rd Order  tensor such that its inner product with the vector $\frac{\partial {{\bf \overrightarrow u}}}{\partial {t}}$ would yield a matrix (2nd order tensor). My question is whether there is some way clever around explicitly evaluating this 3rd Order tensor.

Some guidance and/or suggestions here would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: $
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
$You don't need the chain rule, simply do a component-wise calculation
$$\large{
\dot A
 = \mc{
-\dot v & f'(p)\;\dot p \\\hline
g'(p)\;\dot p & -\dot v \\
} 
}$$

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention why term-by-term differentiation w.r.t. $t$ wouldn't be convenient for me, so I've modified the OP.

Comment: You’d better assume $f,g$ are differentiable, likewise $p$ and $v$.

Comment: Ted, yes they are - they are thermophysical properties of a compressible fluid.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Unvec#1{\op{Unvec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\mr#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Use [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) to calculate a matrix-valued *Jacobian* instead of a $3^{rd}$order tensor, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
a &= \vecc{A} &= \mr{-v \\ g \\ f \\ -v} \qiq
\grad au
 &= \mr{0 & -\o \\ g' & 0 \\ f' & 0 \\ 0 & -\o}
\quad
}$$
Then calculate the time-derivative as
$$\eqalign{
\grad at &= \gradLR au \gradLR ut \qiq
\grad At &= \Unvec{\grad at} \\
}$$
In many computer languages, `vec()` and `Unvec()` are implemented via a `reshape()` function incurring no extra storage and virtually zero cost.